# Menu que se move por coordenadas

Tags: javascript, menu, coordenadas

Estou fazendo [este site](http://progdesenv.com.br/edermiguel/) mas não consigo fazer duas coisas:

1. o menu tem que se mover para os conteúdos conforme eu clico nas opções
2. quando a página carregar tem que aparecer centralizado juntamente com o menu onde tem o Instagram.

Procurei vários métodos na net de fazer o menu se mover e percebi que o jeito de fazer isso é por coordenadas x e y só que não achei nenhum exemplo de como fazer.

Já a parte do *load* eu não achei um código que fizesse tal coisa.

Comment: Não tem nada a ver com a pergunta mas: No post-it que está a música barulho na cama está escrito *barAlho na cama** na parte de baixo. Depois q ver eu excluo o comentário.

Comment: Achei a pergunta muito interessante, principalmente pelo mecanismo de interação que você está bolando para o site. Uma curiosidade: por acaso o seu projeto considera que grande parte do público utilizará dispositivos móveis com interação por toque (*touchscreen*)? Pergunto isso porque sob um ponto de vista de usabilidade creio que faltam indicações visuais da continuidade do espaço e, estritamente sob o ponto de vista do ambiente desktop, o "clicar e arrastar" pareceu cansativo. Talvez isso até seja um gancho para uma ou duas outras perguntas... Eu acho que faltam perguntas de UX por aqui. :)

Comment: Luiz, o site não foi feito para celular realmente, somenta para desktop, o conceito de arrastar é somente uma opção secundária por quando o site estiver completo ele carregará diretamente no conteúdo central com o menu em cima. E a idéia é que a pessoa veja que tem mais coisas para o lado e clique no menu para vê-las. Se pudesse mudaria algumas coisas mas sabe como é cliente né hehehe

Comment: Sim, eu havia entendido essa dinâmica da própria pergunta. Ainda assim, sugiro que você faça umas avaliações com potenciais usuários pra coletar *feedback*. Dependendo do que ELES falarem, acho que o seu cliente é capaz de ouvir.

Answer (score 4):

Da pra fazer tanto usando JavaScript Puro quanto jQuery pelo que eu vi em seu projeto você já esta utilizando jQuery então montei um exemplo pra você utilizando jQuery pois o código fica mais simples.

HTML

```
<div id="menu" class='source'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#contato" class='menu'>contato</a></li>
        <li><a href="#quemsomos" class='menu'>quemsomos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#redessociais" class='menu'>redessociais</a></li>
        <li><a href="#teste" class='menu'>Teste</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="contato" class='source'><h2>contato</h2></div>
<div id="quemsomos"  class='source'><h2>quemsomos</h2></div>
<div id="redessociais"  class='source'><h2>redessociais<h2></div>
<div id="teste"  class='source'><h2>Teste<h2></div>
```

CSS

```
.source{
    position:absolute;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;        
}
#contato{  
    left:50px;
    top:300px;   
    background:#f00;
}
#quemsomos{
    left:1500px;
    top:500px;   
    background:#0f0;
}
#redessociais{
    left:600px;
    top:2000px;   
    background:#00f;

}    
#teste{
    left:500px;
    top:700px;
    background:#cccccc;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu").on("click",function(e){
        // Pega as dimensões da janela
        var W = $(window).width();
        var H = $(window).height();

        // Pega as coordenadas e dimensões do elemento
        var elem = $($(this).attr("href"));
        var x = elem.position().left;
        var y = elem.position().top;
        var h = elem.height();
        var w = elem.width();

        // Calcula as coordenadas que a tela tem que ser rolada para centralizar o elemento
        x -= W/2 - w/2;
        y -= H/2 - h/2;

        $("body").animate({scrollTop:y,scrollLeft:x},400,"swing",function() {
            var x = $("body").scrollLeft();
            var y = $("body").scrollTop();
            $("#menu").css({top:y,left:x});
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    })
})
```

> [Link do exemplo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CAaV9/5/)

---

Tomei a liberdade de olhar o código do seu site e vi que a `DIV` que recebe o conteúdo é a `#ib-main-wrapper` seguindo o exemplo que estou postando você terá que substituir o `$("body")` da animação pela sua div que recebe o conteudo `$("#ib-main-wrapper")`

> **Créditos** a [edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16662/menu-que-se-move-por-coordenadas/16664#comment31230_16664) do @LuizVieira pela colaboração na solução.

Comment: @LuizVieira Vamos lá está quase certo agora, eu fui até o main.js e limpei tudo o que não precisava estar ali. Agora o menu se move só acho que não me expressei direito, pois, quando ele se mover ele tem uma direção específica que seria em cima por exemplo de teste e assim também é com os outros. Quanto ao processo de load da página quando carregar pela primeira vez ele tem que carregar por ex: no elemento teste juntamente com o menu em cima dele. Aqui está o link da página atualizada http://progdesenv.com.br/edermiguel/teste.html

Comment: @LuizVieira 
"2) nos links dos itens do menu mantenha apenas o identificador da âncora (sem o endereço completo do seu site). Por exemplo: <li><a href="#contato" class="menu">contato</a></li>"
Quanto a essa parte eu verifiquei e não tem nenhum link somente as ancoras

Comment: @user4451 Colocar o menu sobre o elemento é questão apenas de não usar os valores de `scrollTop` e `scrollLeft`, e sim as coordenadas x e y do próprio elemento (que você já tem!). Se você descontar alguns pixels de y, o menu ficará acima do elemento.

Answer (score -2):

Eu entendi que você precisa que ao clicar em um link do menu, seja direcionado para a div em um efeito de animação horizontal ou vertical. Se for isso, você pode usar este exemplo e modificar a animação para a div do menu. **[Link do exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/bwg8R/)**

Comment: Acredito que sua resposta não ajuda muito a solução do problema do autor da pergunta, para ter uma ideia de como responder pelo fato de você ser novo no stackoverflow use essa [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16664/5082) como exemplo